# How can I use Nirsoft ProduKey to get the Windows licenses/versions running on our LAN?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I understand from reading [this blog post](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2011/04/get-product-keys-from-computers-across-your-network/) that I should be able to use Nirsoft ProduKey to get the Windows licenses/versions running on our LAN.

I have downloaded it, and set it to scan our LAN and I see it going through each computer in the status bar "Connecting to ..." about 100 computers that we have on our LAN but once it is complete the window shows only the Windows licenses/versions that I have on the computer that I am running the scan from and another computer on our LAN running Windows XP.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOq28.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrEqm.png]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right Click [this](http://silocal.info/WindowsKey.ps1) and select `Save As`
2. Save the script
3. Open PowerShell as admin
4. Input this: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
5. Press Enter
6. Input this and hit enter: `Import-Module C:\Users\Winaero\Desktop\GetProductKey.ps1; Get-WindowsKey`

This will return the PC Name, Version, and the Product Key. The only downside to this is that you have to do this on every PC.

---

As For NirSoft ProduKey, if you know the DHCP scope/IP Range of those PCs, use that option.

e.g. `192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.110`

Comment: I'm not having much luck. It is only showing the Windows licenses/versions that I have on the computer that I am running the scan from and another computer on our LAN running Windows XP even though I see a "Connecting to ..." line for all computers.

Comment: try the powershell script BTW, it's for Vista+

Comment: Will it produce the correct details on 7 and 8 also (but not XP right?)? I might go down the manual route and use that script. I've spent 2 hours trying to get that program to work and I could have done it all by now!

Comment: Is there any way to get it so that I just double click the script on the desktop and it shows the information in a window? Rather than having to invoke a manual shell and write those commands.

Comment: not really, as PS would exit after echoing the info

Comment: @Jack sorry I couldn't have been more helpful than PowerShell